# How to use allocatable character in a Fortran common block?

Tags: fortran, character, fortran-common-block

I am trying to have an allocatable character inside a common block, in Fortran 77. But the compiler always complains

```sh
Error: COMMON attribute conflicts with ALLOCATABLE attribute at (1)
```

The code I had is

```
      subroutine word()
          character (len = :), allocatable :: a
          common /a/ a
          a = 'word'
      end subroutine word

      program main
          character (len = :), allocatable :: a
          common /a/ a
          call word()
          print *, a
      end program main
```

The only way that I saw to make it work is not to use `allocatable`

```
      subroutine word()
          character * 4 :: a
          common /a/ a
          a = 'word'
      end subroutine word

      program main
          character * 4 :: a
          common /a/ a
          call word()
          print *, a
      end program main
```

But this would be cumbersome because I would have to know the length of a character in advance.

How could I make `allocatable` to work in a `common` block?

Comment: The linked question asks about allocatable arrays, but the question and answer hold for all allocatable objects.

Comment: You couldn't have allocatable anything in Fortran 77 - these new fangled things were only introduced in 1990. So as you are not using Fortran 77 but something more modern please don't use common which are evil, use modules instead

Comment: @IanBush Thanks, I just have to work in Fortran 77 with `common` in some historic code.